# WIX + LAMP under one domain

Tags: apache, lamp

I’m trying to get my head around a problem and hoping for some clarity
I have built a basic LAMP site running on a VPS.
My client also has a site built on WIX (online website builder)

I would like to get both sites running under the one domain name. Perfect solution would be (though I don’t believe is possible):

- example.com - WIX
- example.com - WIX
- example.com/y - LAMP
- example.com/z - LAMP

My next idea would be to use subdomains:

- www.example.com - WIX
- xyz.example.com - LAMP

Is any of the above possible when trying to work with WIX and LAMP setups without spending lots of money on something like nginx? Or do I just have to use different domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with WIX ecosystem but I think that the path of least resistance is to just setup a subdomain using DNS records.

Refer to your DNS manager, but basically you just want to add an `A` record.

Your DNS records might look like

```
example.com.       A    1.2.3.4
www.example.com.   A    1.2.3.4
```

So you will just need to add

```
xyz.example.com.   A    5.6.7.8
```

If your DNS records are managed by WIX, I found the proper [documentation](https://support.wix.com/en/article/connecting-a-subdomain-to-an-external-resource-eg-a-blog).

---

By the way, Nginx open source is free. Nginx plus is a paid service that includes some goodies on top. [Blog post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/whats-difference-nginx-foss-nginx-plus/) [Feature comparison](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/#compare-versions)

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a try but it looks like WIX have some URL validation in place and I got their error page "Looks Like This Domain Isn't Connected To A Website Yet!"

Comment: @Tobe_Sta You might want to wait for a while, DNS propagation can sometimes take a couple of hours.